# Inconsistent behavior for INDEX(MATCH())

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a workbook with sheets `s1` and `s2`.  For a given value in column U of `s1`, I want to determine whether or not it exists in column G of `s2` using INDEX(MATCH()).  I'm not using VLOOKUP because I'm actually trying to do a multiple-criteria lookup, and I'm following the approach described [here](http://exceltactics.com/vlookup-multiple-criteria-using-index-match/); this is just the simplest case with a single-criterion lookup.

When I use the formula:

```
=INDEX('S2'!A1:Q2945,MATCH(1,'S2'!G1:G2945='S1'!U4,0),2)
```

I get an #N/A error of "Value not Available".

But when I use either of the following formulas:

```
=VLOOKUP('S1'!U4,'S2'!G1:G2945,1,FALSE)
=INDEX('S2'!A1:Q2945,MATCH('S1'!U4,'S2'!G1:G2945,0),2)
```

then the lookup is successful.

I've verified that the values match by copying the value of U4 from `S1` and searching for it on `S2`.

Why am I getting the "Value not Available" error from the first formula?

Comment: At a quick glance, I'd suggest that this component of your MATCH() function is most likely the cause: 'S2'!G1:G2945='S1'!U4.  The second argument of a MATCH() function needs to be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Written as an answer to close out this question, the MATCH() function in your equation is specifying more than an array as its second argument.


Your existing formula:

```
=INDEX('S2'!A1:Q2945,MATCH(1,'S2'!G1:G2945='S1'!U4,0),2)
```

... should be corrected to the following (with "**='S1'!U4**" removed):

```
=INDEX('S2'!A1:Q2945,MATCH(1,'S2'!G1:G2945,0),2)
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers!